# Licensing Module for PHP based project

Tags: php, licensing

I am looking for a 3rd party licensing module that can be incorporated into my PHP project. I can always implement a custom one but client needs to understand if there are any 3rd party options readily available...

does any such 3rd party module exist at all for PHP... such are availabe for .Net but couldn't find any for PHP...

Thanks in advance

Regards,

ASV

Comment: What do you mean by `licensing module`?

Comment: I have many licensing modules at home, I can send you one if you want. I don't exactly know what they are, though.

Comment: Closing as not a real question. Its too vague to be a dupe, though it is a dupe. Can you edit this to add more specifics as to what you want to accomplish? I.e., do you want to `obfuscate` your code and make sure the people who use it have a valid license to do so? Or do you want to run some kind of licensing _server_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question on what you mean with *licensing module* is not very clear, but if you mean what I think you do you could check out the [Ioncube loader](http://www.ioncube.com/) or [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/).

Comment: I don't think you mean what you think you mean... You think he was talking about encoding the php code?

Comment: when i say Licensing Module, i mean a framework which can be used to implement licensing of my product. I can reinvent the wheel but if its already available would like to evaluate the same... this is for a portal developed in php... the client would now want to co-brand his portal with others and wants the ability to control this by implementing some licensing strategy..

Comment: I think what you mean is a subscription and reseller possibiliy. For that you will need some framework that is capable of user management and ACL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list)

Comment: Thank you Daff, its exactly the scenario you thought...Subscription and reseller possibility.. how about GNU GPL used for commercial... could that be a possibility or may be MIT License...???

Comment: Pretty much any major PHP framework like Zend or CakePHP supports some kind of user and rights management...

Comment: Yes Daff you are indeed correct.. Zend provides the solution so does.. Nu-Coder PHP encoder.. PHP License Manager Pro... and PADL(NOT YET STABLE THOUGH)